# why I failed to get FromVC and ToVC with [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewKey]

Tags: ios, transition, interactive

I get a problem:

when I try to Override method `startInteractiveTransition:` I tried to save `transitionContext`, and fetch `FromVC` and `ToVC` from `transitionContext`
but failed, I do not know why? anyone have ideas?

here is code:

```
-(void)startInteractiveTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    self.transitionContext = transitionContext;
    id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning> transitionContext01 = self.transitionContext;
    if (self.transitionContext) {
        NSLog(@"start里为空");
    }else
    {
        NSLog(@"start里不为空");
    }
    NSLog(@"执行了start");
    UIViewController * fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewKey];
    if (fromVC) {
        NSLog(@"start里fromVC为空");
    }else
    {
        NSLog(@"start里fromVC不为空");
    }
    UIViewController * toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewKey];
    if (toVC) {
        NSLog(@"start里toVC为空");
    }else
    {
        NSLog(@"start里toVC不为空");
    }
    [[transitionContext containerView] bringSubviewToFront:fromVC.view];
    toVC.view.alpha = self.behindViewAlpha;
}
```

Here is screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUYl9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the issur by myself
Not `UITransitionContextToViewKey`
But `UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey`